# How to fix "System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: entity'"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I get this error

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: entity'

This is my code:

```
namespace CodeFirstFinal
{
    class Program
    {
        public static Category category { get; private set; }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var db = new CategoryContext())
            {
                Console.Write("Enter a name for a new Error category:");
                var name = Console.ReadLine();

                var blog = new Category { Name = name };
                db.Categories.Add(category);
                db.SaveChanges();

                var query = from c in db.Categories
                            orderby c.Name
                            select c;

                foreach (var item in query)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Category
    {
        public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Error> Errors { get; set; }
    }

    public class Error
    {
        public int? ErrorId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }

        public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    }

    public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    }

    public class CategoryContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Error> Errors { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .Property(u => u.DisplayName)
                .HasColumnName("display_area");
        }
    }
}
```

Error occurs on this line of code:

```
db.Categories.Add(category);
```

I am new to programming and would appreciate any help.

Thank you!

Comment: You don't show where `category` is assigned. Did you mean to write `db.Categories.Add(blog);`?

Comment: Your property `category` isn't getting set , which means it is `null` when you add it to `Categories`. Maybe you want to set assign `blog` to `category` first before adding.

Answer (score 0):

```
            var name = Console.ReadLine();
            var category = new Category { Name = name };
            db.Categories.Add(category);
```

You need to write code like above i hope that will solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

You are not initialising the Category property and therefore you are passing it as a null value to the Add method which is an error. Either you initialise the Category property or pass the blog variable.